# A generic version of python's `str.zfill` that supports arbitrary fillers?

Tags: python

`str.zfill` is a useful tool to pad strings with leading zeros:

```
In [1]: '123'.zfill(5)
Out[1]: '00123'
```

However, is there a more generic version that will take any filler character and pad a string with it? I'm looking for something like this:

```
In []: 'txt'.foo(' ', 5)
Out[]: '   txt'

In []: '12'.foo('#', 5)
Out[]: '###12'
```

Does such a function exist?

Comment: I'm pretty amazed this question hasn't been asked before...

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake I'm surprised vaultah hasn't come swooping down on his magical flying carpet with his dupe hammer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are the string justification methods, [`ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) and [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust).

```
>>> '12'.rjust(5, '#')
'###12'
>>> 'txt'.rjust(5, ' ')
'  txt'
>>> '12'.ljust(5, '#')
'12###'
```

Comment: This is nice. I did not know `str.xjust` took a second parameter!

Comment: @COLDSPEED If only there was a Hoogle for Python

Answer (score 1):

Implementing your own version should be straightforward enough:

```
def xfill(string, num, filler='0'):
    if len(filler) != 1:
        raise TypeError('xfill() expected a character, but string of length %d found' %len(filler))
    return filler * max(0,  num - len(string)) + string
```

The `assert` ensures the filler is a single, valid character only.

---

`xfill(string, num [, filler])`:

1. `string`: the string to be padded
2. `num`: the total width of the field (similar to `str.zfill`)
3. `filler`: to pad with. Defaults to `0` to mimic `str.zfill` functionality

---

Examples:

```
In [321]: xfill('123', 5)
Out[321]: '00123'

In [322]: xfill('123', 5, '#')
Out[322]: '##123'
```

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Maybe... I don't know how to use format that way :)

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Turn it into an answer!

Comment: Done. Gobbledygook to please the SO algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is simple padding, I'd go with  @PM2Ring's answer, but there is another, more versatile way, using the `str.format` method (Python 2.6 onward). This method allows you to interpolate the format specifier by nesting the replacement fields:

```
'{string:{fill}>{num}}'.format(string=string, fill=fill, num=num)
```

Replace `>` with `<` if you need to left-align the string instead.

Comment: The `str.format` method was added in 2.6, and I just tested your code successfully in 2.6.6.

Comment: Yes, `str.format` has been around for a while, but I don't think it's always supported 'dynamic' specifiers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `str.format` has always supported nested replacement fields; they're mentioned in [the 2.6 docs](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax); FWIW, `str.format` was back-ported to 2.6 from Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

To add a little more flexibility for alternative patterns instead of just a character:

```
def filler(string, pattern, width):
    left_filler = (pattern * width)[:max(0, width - len(string))]
    return left_filler + string

>>> filler(string='some text', pattern='*.', width=15)
# Output:
# '*.*.*.some text'

>>> filler(string='some text', pattern='*.', width=14)
# Output:
# '*.*.*some text'
```